# Report Builder 3.0 chart series custom sort

Tags: t-sql, sorting, bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I need to add "Total" category in a bar chart in Report Builder. But there are percentage values(I can't aggregate them with SUM() function) so I have to customize my SQL code or write an expression for totals. I couldn't find anything to add Totals into charts in Report Builder interface so I decided to add a "Total" row by SQL but charts automatically sorts data A-Z or Z-A. How can I manipulate this feature? Adding Total group in chart series is the logical option, if you know how to add I prefer that.

To sort series, I tried IIF() function to change order of data in "Series Group Properties" window but I failed.

(like this we do in SQL

```
order by case when ColumnName = 'T' then '10' else ColumnName end desc
```

)

When I manipulate data by SQL to add Totals my data is like this in the chart:

P - Q - R - S - Total - W

I want it to be like this:

P - Q - R - S - W - Total